# Strange desktop behavior seems to "randomly" occur

Tags: release-hera, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop

Please bear with me because I do not know what is causing this issue or how to reproduce it. I wrote randomly in the title because I am not sure if there is something I am doing (e.g. some unfortunate combination of key strokes) that causes this behavior.

Sometimes while using my computer, the desktop will start behaving strangely. That is, the left mouse button will stop working. It will still work to select different windows that are open, but I will not be able to click on anything within those windows, I won't be able to close those windows, and I cannot select from the menu to shutdown the computer.

The keys will somehow also become re-mapped. For example, pressing "o" will toggle screen rotation lock, pressing "w" or the down arrow key will toggle Multitasking View, and pressing "1" and "2" will switch between work spaces. If I am in a terminal window and press "t", it will open a new terminal window. While in a terminal, I will not be able to type anything.

As I said, I have no idea how to reproduce this behavior, it seems to happen randomly and when it does happen I have no other option but to do a hard shut down. I do not know what kind of information people may need to diagnose and solve the problem, so I will be happy to try and respond to any questions. I am definitely not an expert Linux user, or someone who is very computer savvy. Further information:

> OS:  elementary OS 5.1.4 Hera x86_64
>
> Host: 80V4 Lenovo YOGA 710-14IKB
>
> Kernel: 4.15.0-101-generic

Thank you in advance for any guidance or help.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying to update the kernel with a more recent one, if you don't have any specific reason to stay on 4.15.

Latest is 5.3.0-53-generic.

To get there:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

From now on, you will receive in AppCenter the new kernel updates.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. I know it's not a great question because I cannot reproduce it. In fact, it just happened again. I tried to duplicate the issue after restarting by pressing some of the last key strokes I might have accidentally pressed, but no luck. I'll try this update and see what happens.